# Добавить 8 часов к времени - PHP

Tags: php

Есть переменная `$orders.datetime`, она берет из базы данных `datetime` и выводит на сайт. Как сделать так, чтобы к времени прибавлялось `8` часов?

Comment: В каком формате оно в базе? Unix timestamp? Тогда прибавляйте к значению 8*3600.

Comment: оно в формате [d-m-y h:i:s]

Comment: Формат поля в базе DATETIME или строковый? Какая СУБД? Если DATETIME и mysql - посмотрите в сторону функции ADDTIME().

Comment: формат поля - DATETIME

Comment: Тогда смотрите на ADDTIME, сразу из базы можно будет дергать увеличенное на 8 часов время.

Comment: @Alex mysql использую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть три варианта ответа на вопрос, в зависимости от того, как хранится дата и время.

Если дата и время хранится в виде UNIX time, то это по сути целое число — количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970-го года (т.н. *эпоха UNIX*). Прибавляйте `8 * 3600`, как советует Владимир Мартьянов.

Если дата и время хранится в поле вида DATETIME и загружается в виде объекта PHP `DateTime`, то можно воспользоваться методом прибавления интервала:

```
$interval8Hours = new DateInterval('8h');
$date->add($interval8Hours);
```

Наконец, если дата и время хранится в виде строки, необходимо конвертировать её либо в UNIX time, либо в `DateTime`. В первом случае можно воспользоваться функцией `strtotime`, во втором — конструктором класса.

Comment: Спасибо большое, способ с интервалом помог

Answer (score 0):

Думается мне вам нужно работать с конкретной таймзоной.

Вот пример:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimestamp(1297869844);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Krasnoyarsk'));

echo $date->format('d-m-y h:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Для случая *mysql* и поля типа `DATETIME` можно использовать функцию `ADDTIME()` из *mysql*.